# how can I append duplicated values under an existing empty column for the same ID

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataset consisting of 1000's of grouped data, for each group I am trying do a linear regression and find values for 6 different parameters. Since it was a large dataset, I worked with only one group to begin with.

I read it in as a pandas dataframe and made a subset dataframe containing only one group.

```
#EXTRACTING STARTING PARAMETER VALUES for just 1 group
a = code to calculate parameter & returns a singular number...
b = ...
c = ...
d = ...
e = ...
f = ...
```

I found out it's parameters and added 6 new columns to store the values.
I used:

```
df = df.assign(log_B0=a, E=b, Eh=c, El=d, Th=e, Tl=f)
```

to create the new columns whilst storing the value which is repeated down the column for that particular group.

I am using a loop to calculate the parameters for each group using:

```
for i, g in df.groupby('uniqueID'):
```

But I am having trouble appending the output parameter values for each group to the original dataframe.

I think i need to use:

```
g.assign(log_B0=...)
```

..to append the parameter values for each group to the columns.
But that only saves it for the last group and I also don't want to keep adding a new column header.

Do I need to increment?

I want the output like this:

[parameter values log_B0, E..etc for the two groups 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd1A8.png)

Comment: It appears you seem to be using some kind of library/module you have not identified...

Comment: I'm using pandas dataframe to read in my initial dataframe

Comment: Can you create a small dataframe with groups and your scalar values, then show the desired output from that sample dataframe and scalar values?